# Explain Shift Adder multiplication

Tags: python-3.x, binary

Can some one explain the Shift Adder method of multiplication of binary values to me in dummy terms don't understand it as is let alone write a program to compute answers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know the standard multiplication method by paper pencil (aka [Long multiplication method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication))

Binary shift & add and long multiplication method method are very similar.

For e.g. In the long multiplication method, if you want to multiply binary number 1001 by 1011, the procedure would look like:

```
         1 0 0 0
       x 1 0 1 1
  ---------------
         1 0 0 0  ( Step 1: 1000 x LSB (bit 0) of 1011, which is 1, followed by 0 shift to the left)
+      1 0 0 0 -  ( Step 2: 1000 x bit 1 of 1011, which is again 1, followed by 1 shift to the left)
+    0 0 0 0 - -  ( Step 3: 1000 x bit 2 of 1011, which is 0, followed by 2 shifts to the left)
+  1 0 0 0 - - -  ( Step 4: 1000 x MSB (bit 3) of 1011 which is 1 again, followed by 3 shifts to the left)
 ----------------
   1 0 1 1 0 0 0  ( Step 5: Add all the above)
 ----------------
```

Now in shift and add method, you do not do the addition (step 5) in the end, rather we keep adding the numbers on the fly as shown below:

```
Step 0: Result = 0
Step 1: Result = Result + Step 1 of Long division (1000 x LSB (bit 0) of 1011, which is 1, followed by 0 shift)
               = 0000 + 1000
               = 1000
Step 2: Result = Result + Step 2 of Long division (1000 x bit 1 of 1011, which is again 1, followed by 1 shift)
               = 1000 + 10000 (Additional zero at the end of second term is due to shifting 1000 to the left by 1 time: 1000_0)
               = 11000

Step 3: Result = Result + Step 3 of Long division (1000 x bit 2 of 1011, which is 0, followed by 2 shift)
               = 11000 + 000000
               = 11000
Step 4: Result = Result + Step 4 of Long division (1000 x MSB (bit 3) of 1011 which is 1 again, followed by 3 shift)
               = 11000 + 1000000 (Additional zeros at the end of second term is due to shifting 1000 to the left three times: 1000_000)
               = 1011000
```

The above algorithm should be more than enough for you to start coding I hope.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. Is this way more efficient for computers since less memory is required to store values that are being calculated upon (as the result keeps changing)

Comment: While this may be a memory efficient method compared to a lot of other algorithms, I'm not sure whether this is the best method out there as far as memory efficiency is concerned. One drawback of this method is that it sacrifices clock cycles for memory efficiency. If you look at long multiplication, we can get the final results in two clock cycles: Step 1, 2 3 4 can be done in parallel, each taking one clock cycle. In the next clock cycle you add all the results of the above (Step 5) and get the final result. Shift adder on the other hand takes 4 clock cycles to get to the final result